# ¿como puedo enviar datos de desde un servlet a dos vistas JSP o mas?

Tags: java-ee

estoy haciendo un proyecto universitario el cual simula el comportamiento de un computador manejo de memoria y compilación de programas, he llegado a toparme con el problema de que necesito que en el momento de ejecutar un programa ademas de cargarme las lineas de código en un textarea que(ya funciona previamente) también en el mismo instante necesito cargar información de el nombre del programa cantidad de instrucciones etc, en un JSP diferente al del textarea ya que se carga en un iframe especifico mediante un target. Como puedo puedo actualizar la información al tiempo. mil gracias por su ayuda, acepto soluciones que consistan en modificar la estructura del programa, programo en Java pero soy nuevo en el tema Java EE y ni se diga en Front-end.

Aquí el código.

servlet:

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author GEORGE
 */
@WebServlet(name = "LeerArchivo", urlPatterns = {"/LeerArchivo"})
public class LeerArchivo extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
//            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
//            out.println("<html>");
//            out.println("<head>");
//            out.println("<title>Servlet LeerArchivo</title>");
//            out.println("</head>");
//            out.println("<body>");

            String ruta = "C:\\Users\\GEORGE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ChMaquina\\web\\ArchivosCh\\";
            File dir = new File(ruta);

            String[] nombreArchivos = dir.list();
            // out.print(request.getParameter("cargar"));
            try {

                FileReader archivo = new FileReader(ruta + request.getParameter("cargar"));
                BufferedReader filtro = new BufferedReader(archivo);

                String li = filtro.readLine();

                ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (li != null) {
                    out.println("<h4>" + li + "</h4>");

//                out.println("<h4>"+filtro.readLine()+"</h4>");
                    lista.add(li);
                    li = filtro.readLine();

                }
                filtro.close();

                if (request.getParameter("cargar") != "") {
                    request.setAttribute("nombre", request.getParameter("cargar"));
                    request.setAttribute("lista", lista);
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("dirPantalla/Texto.jsp").forward(request, response);

                } else {
                    out.print("no encontrado");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.print("Excepcion: " + e.getMessage());
            }

//            for (String re : nombreArchivos) {
//                out.print(re + "<br>");
////            }
//            out.println("</body>");
//            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

JSP Texto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>


<h3><%= request.getAttribute("nombre")%> </h3> 

<% ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("lista"); %>
<table style="width: 300px; height: 200px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <textarea style="width: 30px; height: 2200px; align-items: left; resize: none" disable="true"><%

                    for (int i = 1; i <= lista.size(); i++) {
                        out.print(i + "\n");
                    }
                %>
            </textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 2200px; align-items: left; resize: none"><%
                    for (String list : lista) {
                        out.print(list + "\n");
                    }
                %>



            </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSP Programa: Aquí debe de ir la información correspondiente reemplazando las variables i del for por la información real.

La idea es poder enviar el ArrayList a estos dos JSP para realizar el respectivo Tratamiento.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Programa</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/img_default/index.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="../css/bootstrap.css.map" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="../css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.css.map" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" mdia="screen" href="../css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css">


        <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../js/npm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-responsive label-default small">
            <tr> 
                <td>
                    ID
                </td>
                <td>
                    Programa
                </td>
                <td>
                    Ints
                </td>
                <td>
                    TLL
                </td>
                <td>
                    RLC
                </td>
                <td>
                    RLP
                </td>
            </tr>
                <% for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    out.print("<tr><td>000"+i+"</td><td>Programa.ch"+i+"</td><td>"+(i+77)+"</td><td>"+(i+50)+"</td><td>"+(i+50)+"</td><td>"+(i+50)+"</td></tr>");






                }
                %>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mil gracias por su ayuda. :)

Comment: Te recomiendo no usar Java dentro de los JSP, usa [EL](https://openwebinars.net/blog/jsp-standard-tag-library-jstl-y-expression-language-el/)

Comment: Gracias por el consejo lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como presentas el problema te digo que no se puede hacer. Desde el cliente(jsp) se envía una petición al servidor(servlet), este la procesa y redirige a otra vista. No hay más. No se puede redirigir a dos sitios.

Lo que puedes hacer es teniendo los datos en tu primera página, al terminar la carga (onload o simplemente ejecutar js al final de la página), por javascript cargar contenido en la otra página. Pero esto te dará problemas de crossframe scripting. Si tu segunda página estuviese en un div (podrías cargarlo por ajax) entonces no tendrías este problema.

Creo que deberías replantearte el diseño de tu aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, el problema básicamente es que no se mucho de JavaScript ni el manejo muy bien de los frameworks, y necesito implementar Hilos en el proyecto para manejar la velocidad de compilación. por eso me quede en mi zona de confort(Java). en fin la pregunta es Como podría replantearse mejor el diseño? muchas gracias.

Comment: Si quieres algo similar a hilos en javascript puedes usar `settimeout` y/o `setInterval` y su pareja `clearInterval`. Ademas creo que te conviene revisar `window.open`, `window.opener`, `window.parent`,`window.top`, etc.